# Trouble with Xcode Script

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In the .m file in my script i keep getting an error like this error:

> `no declaration of property
>   "newGameButton" found in interface`

I also get this with the "statsButton" and "settingsButton". here is my script:

```
#import "MainMenuViewController.h"
#import "Traffic_2AppDelegate.h"
#import "TrafficViewController.h"

@implementation MainMenuViewController
-(IBAction) newGame:(id)sender {
    TrafficViewController* traffic = [[TrafficViewController alloc]
                                          initWithNibName:@"TrafficViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:traffic animated:NO]; 
}

-(IBAction) showStats:(id)sender {
}

-(IBAction) showSettings:(id)sender {
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [popAnimation setDuration:0.3];

    [newGameButton setHidden:YES];
    [statsButton setHidden:YES];
    [settingsButton setHidden:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(popView:) withObject:newGameButton afterDelay:0.25];
    [self performSelector:@selector(popView:) withObject:statsButton afterDelay:0.3];
    [self performSelector:@selector(popView:) withObject:settingsButton afterDelay:0.35];

}

@synthesize newGameButton, statsButton, settingsButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    popAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    popAnimation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
    popAnimation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.01],
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1],
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

    [popAnimation retain];
}

- (void)popView:(UIView*)view {
    [view setHidden:NO];
    [[view layer] addAnimation:popAnimation forKey:@"transform.scale"];
}

@end
```

Comment: What does your `@interface` block for the class look like?

Answer (score 0):

You've got the line:

`@synthesize newGameButton, statsButton, settingsButton;`

You haven't shown us the interface (.h) file, but I'd be willing to bet that you don't have a @property declaration for newGameButton, statsButton, or settingsButton. Those should look something like:

`@property(retain, nonatomic) UIButton *newGameButton;`

unless they're supposed to be outlets, in which case you'd also want to include `IBOutlet` just before the `UIButton...`